# Is it possible to add a text over a background image in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to add a txt over a image HTML content block. Every time i try different sets of codes it leaves me with the text appearing below/above the image, not on top of it.

Here is a sample code i executed on SFMC.

```
<style>
  .container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 150px;
    top: 350px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg" />
  <p class="text">
    Hello World!
  </p>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the image as a css background image if you want to overlay text over it. e.g.

```
<style>
.container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 150px;
    top: 350px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container" style="background-image: url('http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg');">
  <p class="text">
    Hello World!
  </p>
</div>
```